# How to reorganize microservices when they all share data and concepts?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, microservices

At our company we use the microservices approach because we like to keep services small, understandable and maintainable. Besides that, we use a load balancer which enables us to duplicate heavy used services.

We understand that microservices should be loosely coupled if coupling is needed at all. Also, the coupling should not happen on the database, but preferably by API's (REST).

Well, we use the microservice idea. We don't apply everthing that is recommended. In our case we use loosely coupled Tomcat War's that communicate via REST and JMS messaging. All webapps use the same database server, but they all have their own scheme (so no integration).

We have two issues with this approach:

1. 75% of the services generate report data. There is a report service that is responsible for persistence and serving of that data. So all services that generate report data send their findings to the report-service. In fact, each 
   service has it's own responsibility, but still we need all this communication. This seems to conflict with the microservices idea. It is like a horizontal layer that binds all vertical microservices together.
2. Due to the 'horizontal' coupling above, we also share interface objects. Report data is structured in a certain way. And every service needs to follow that structure. We have a strong feeling that shared libraries of domain / interface objects is against some principles. But as you will understand, duplicating all interface objects seems dumb and still a lot of work when interfaces change.

An alternative to the current architecture is that every service persists it's own report data. Then you only need the communication when the report is rendered. In that case we don't have the regular communication between services and the report-service. Disadvantages are now that every service needs it's database layer (there was no), and that you still need to share report structures among all services.

The high-level question is: is there a pattern for dividing services when behaviour can be separated horizontally and vertically?

The same issue may occur in a sales application where the 'product' plays a central role through the entire set of services.

Should we redesign the architecture? Is there a pattern we can use? or is this an already known anti-pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are alternatives. One of them is called [Self-Contained Systems](http://scs-architecture.org/), which is a "stricter" form of microservices.

The main idea being, that every service should be able to fulfill its role without needing communication with others for the business logic (no synchronous calls during execution to other services). That is what it means to be truly decoupled.

Now obviously services do not exist in a vacuum, so how to we make them play together. There are two preferred ways which still avoid the problems you are facing.

**Offline/Asynchronous Communication**

Data can still flow between services if the data is asynchronous. Asynchronous does not only mean that it should go though a queue or something like that. It means that it is *offline*. It does not happen during the execution of the "business-logic".

So persisting a report, as it is part of the logic, would not be allowed. You can however archive reports later (offline) to a data warehouse system or something. That "main" functionality still works if this offline replication fails or is not available for some time for example.

**Frontend composition**

If you are already using REST, you probably have web-interfaces and other services with links in them.

If you want to present some reports, you can directly link to those reports available at their respective services. You don't really have to copy reports over to some "central" system.

So basically the services are composed through links in the UI.

That means of course, all services should host their own UIs too.

**Anti-patterns to SCSs**

As you said, if you have something like a "product", and you build a separate service for that, you *will* have coupling. Since all others will probably depend on "product", you just created a dependency to all.

In SCS, we don't create services for "things", like *product* or *user*, we create services for functionality like "search", "shopping cart", "configurator", etc. Each of them have their own "product" view. The cool part is, they usually all have different concepts of what a product is, so there is very little duplication or redundancy.

The remaining redundancy is then handled by offline data streams as discussed above.

Answer (score 0):

Reporting often has little to do with your application domain model.  Usually it is a separate, cross-cutting concern, and is implemented at the back-end data store for performance reasons.

Doing a common domain model just for reporting will couple all of your services to an unacceptable degree, you will create a monolith.

It seems like you have created a compromise, where a report service is decoupled by making it it's own service.  This seems reasonable, but like you said, it is causing a lot of communication overhead.  It also imposes a run-time overhead that may or may not be justifiable.

Regardless, like I said, reporting is often cross-cutting, and as such, usually does not fit into a domain model particularly well.  The decision to either move it into a back-end process vs making it a run-time process like you have depends on the operational requirements of your system.

I would highly encourage you *not* to try and make all of your microservice domains fit a common model.  This will create a monolith, and will make changes to that domain extraordinarily expensive.  You will have all the overheads of a monolith, plus all the overheads of microservices...

Comment: Well, this is system is about a set of data validators that combine all findings into a single report and send that back to the customer. Every finding has similar attributes like timestamp, severity, code and more. So, it is in fact kind of the domain model.

Comment: Ah, I see, so you aren't reporting on the services, the services ARE to generate the report.  So you have a common report repository that each of these are streaming content to.  The interface for that service is common, and you probably even have a client stub library that you distribute to your other services, but that doesn't mean that the other services integrate that domain model into their own.  They USE that model to write to the external report service, but they don't have that as their own model.

Comment: The trick is to accept that these are external dependencies, and isolate them from your domain model.   If you look at an onion architecture, or ports & adapters, etc, the external dependencies are on the outside, and the domain model is on the inside.  Your domain model talks to these interfaces through your client stub, but it does not integrate them into its own.  It's important to keep this decoupled from your internal domain model.  It is entirely appropriate to make a library out of those interfaces, and put them in an external layer (with your Data Access Layer and such)